# Create a web based GPS Skyplot

Tags: javascript, html, gps

**I am looking to create a web based GPS skyplot.**

Currently just in the planning stages. Was wondering if anyone knew any javascript libraries or such in which this would be best to start with or have a look at, of if you have done something similar before. I know **Flot** is decent for plotting but unsure if it would be easy in this scenario.

---

**TLDR**: Looking for javascript libraries or other alternatives to create a web based GPS Skyplot.

---

**Further info.**

I would like to be able to maintain it all generally in javascript / HTML but am open to other alternatives. I will have a server passing me the GPS details.

---

**Skyplot Examples:** For those who don't know.

http://www.gpsoftnav.com/skyplot.html

http://www.novariant.com/resources/technologies/skyplot.cfm#

---

I came accross:[Geographic Information Systems (Stack Exchange)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems?referrer=kOiYLPl3tWt3hJ0vc5L2Fg2) yesterday, would make a good site for these kind of questions. 
So if anyone is interested in this please also go make a commit :). Otherwise I am still looking for any feedback on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the graphical issues you are concerned with, or are you intending to also calculate which satellites are visible, and their azimuths and elevations at the given location and time?

If it's just the graphical part you are concerned with, I would use jQuery and Keith Wood's SVG plugin - see http://keith-wood.name/svg.html . This gives you a Javascript handle to Scalable Vector Graphics, for drawing circles, lines and dots on a canvas in the web page. It's simple to use, and the page I've linked to has examples that should help.

Comment: Good example, I would have said at the time my own graphical knowledge was not enough to do it myself and was more looking for a third party support however this is no longer the case.